# No me retorna el campo NULL

Tags: mysql

Buen dia, quisiera que me ayudaran con este inconveniente, esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT Nombre, Cedula, sum(HorasTrabajo) as HorasTrabajo FROM reportebeteitiva
                                       group by Cedula WITH ROLLUP;
```

Da como resultado:

```
_________________________________________
|  Nombre  |   Cedula   |  HorasTrabajo |
-----------------------------------------
|Gragorio  | 105460452  |       8       |
-----------------------------------------
|Valentina | 10546565   |      16       |
-----------------------------------------
| Keylor   | 105632514  |      26       |
-----------------------------------------
| Keylor   |     NULL   |      50       |
-----------------------------------------
```

Como ven el WITH ROLLUP me funciona correctamente, pero en la fila final en la del resultado no me devuelve el NULL en Keylor, ese es lo que todavia no me funciona, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No amigo ya lo habia intentado y me salen dos agrupaciones, por nombre y por cedula, solo la necesito por cedula, gracias por el aporte :D

Answer (score 2):

Despues de tanto buscar encontre una respuesta que encaja en el resultado que yo esperaba:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT Nombre, Cedula, sum(HorasTrabajo) as HorasTrabajo FROM reportebeteitiva 
     group by Nombre, Cedula WITH rollup
)A WHERE isnull(Nombre) = isnull(Cedula);
```

Este es el resulatado:

```
_________________________________________
|  Nombre  |   Cedula   |  HorasTrabajo |
-----------------------------------------
|Gragorio  | 105460452  |       8       |
-----------------------------------------
|Valentina | 10546565   |      16       |
-----------------------------------------
| Keylor   | 105632514  |      26       |
-----------------------------------------
|   NULL   |    NULL    |      50       |
-----------------------------------------
```